# Reading android style from xml give different results

Tags: android, android-styles

For example, I have got such style, that's defined in values/styles.xml

```
<style name="subheader">
    <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>
</style>
```

When I trying to read this value like this

```
theme.obtainStyledAttributes(R.style.subheader, new int[]{android.R.attr.padding}).getString(0)
```

All ok, value equals to "10dip". But when I reading values like this

```
theme.obtainStyledAttributes(R.style.subheader, new int[]{android.R.attr.color, android.R.attr.padding}).getString(1)
```

Here is the problem, value is null. Why this happened? How to read this value?

P.S. I need to read all values of any styles. I don't know that "item" is not defined in style.

P.S.S. more complex example

```
<style name="subheader">
    <item name="android:background">#DAE5E9</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>
</style>
```

Result of

```
theme.obtainStyledAttributes(R.style.subheader, new int[]{android.R.attr.background, android.R.attr.layout_margin, android.R.attr.padding})
```

is

```
0:#DAE5E9
1:10dip
2:10dip
```

Result of

```
theme.obtainStyledAttributes(R.style.subheader, new int[]{android.R.attr.background, android.R.attr.layout_margin, android.R.attr.colorBackground, android.R.attr.padding})
```

is

```
0:#DAE5E9
1:10dip
2:null
3:null
```

Comment: Well I assume that the returned TypedArray contains only the attributes found in your style. android.R.attr.color is not defined in your style, so the returned TypedArray must only contain 1 element. Did you try printing "getString(0)" on your second code snippet ?

Comment: Also, to check if an attribute exists, you can use resolveAttribute (returns false if it doesn't exist)

Comment: dqms, getString(0) also equals null.

Comment: I edited my question, and added more complex example.

Comment: It seems that the returned TypedArray stops being populated with results when the first undefined attribute is encountered. a "not very clean" solution would be to try accessing each attribute individually via resolveAttribute to make sure it exists.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, yes, my problem is solved.
So, solution is - read the attributes one by one with calling obtainStyledAttributes for each.